# Implementing a token cache

Tags: multithreading, caching, synchronization, locking, client-server

I am trying to implement a simple cache where my cache will consist of just a latest token returned by authentication server to my application. There are different worker threads which try to login simultaneously to authentication server.This increases load on authentication server and also my application becomes slow as for each authentication thread there is a round trip involved with the server. Hence by implementing a simple token cache, a token will be cached at client side and will be updated only when one of the authentication thread fails to login. Whoever fails will go and fetch a new token from authentication server.

The problem I am getting is when any authentication thread fails and updates the token cache, there might be some threads who already have read the old token and will fail eventually and they also will try to update the cache. How can I stop these threads from updating the cache once it is already updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to assign a timestamp to the retrieved token. Time timestamp does not have to be "real", a sequence number suffices.

When a thread retrieves the token from the token cache, it also retrieves the sequence number associated with the token. When a thread fails to login, it first has to check the local cache again to see if the cache has been refreshed since it retrieved its token. If the sequence number of the current token is different from the one it currently has, it can try again with the token from the cache.

Updating the token cache is necessary only when login fails and the cache has not been refreshed either since the retrieval of the failing token.

There is a slight chance that the sequence number goes a full cycle wrapping around, and a task is mislead to think that the cache has not been refreshed when in fact it has a great number of times, but this is more of a theoretical possibility than a practical concern.

Comment: Nice solution.Just wondering whether a 'long' datatype will suffice for these 'fake' timestamps?

Comment: Well, it depends on the details, but if you take for example a 64-bit unsigned integer and a token timeout of 1 second, then a sequence number roundtrip lasts at least some 500 billion years. Which I think means that it suffices even if your application area is in some way related to intergalactic space travel :)

Comment: Hmmm. Proposed solution does not prevent multiple threads to try getting new token until fresh token is received (this I understood as a request).

Comment: regarding detecting, if the token has be updated or not: Assuming, that tokens are every time different, it is enough to compare old token with current one.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: I think it is assumed that the token cache is accessed using mutual exclusion, that prevents multiple threads to try getting new token

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: I think the general assumption is that tokens are opaque to the clients. They are only allowed to store and present them to the server at appropriate times, but not allowed to examine their content. The purpose of the time stamp is precisely to make tokens comparable. Granted, if they are comparable in the first place, then the time stamp is not needed.

Comment: @xaa you should edit your answer to not, that access to the cache is mutually exclusive. Btw how would you accomplish this?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: how to accomplish mutual exclusion? Well, that is a fairly basic skill. You can use a semaphore or a monitor for example.

Answer (score 1):

When a worker thread fails to log in, it should check the token cache to see if the token has changed from the one it was already issued.  If the cached token has changed, it should use the new cached token instead of seeking a new token.

When a worker thread does seek a new token, it can also keep the old, no longer valid, token.  Then before putting its new token in the cache, it can check if the currently cached token is the same as its old token.

The token cache of course needs to be thread safe and ensure that updates from one thread are seen immediately in other threads, for example by using a volatile reference to the cached token.  This is simpler than keeping a separate time stamp with each token.

Comment: My comment above applies here as well: I think the general assumption is that tokens are opaque to the clients. They are only allowed to store and present them to the server at appropriate times, but not allowed to examine their content. The purpose of the time stamp is precisely to make tokens comparable. Granted, if they are comparable in the first place, then the time stamp is not needed.

Comment: As to your suggestion to get a new token first, then comparing the old with the one in the cache is precisely what the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: The tokens are necessarily stored in memory.  They are opaque in that the client cannot parse them, but the client can still look at their representation in memory.  As for comparisons, I believe the OP just wants to avoid the time required for network round trips.  A memory comparison takes negligible time compared to that.

Comment: You propose that the client first seek a new token, then compare its old with the one in the cache. That means that it might have to dispose its newly acquired token if it finds that the cached token is different from the one it had. That is a network roundtrip was wasted.

Comment: @xxa I think if you read my comment carefully, I propose that the client first compare its old token before seeking a new one.  The reason there's a comparison afterwards is that two workers may end up seeking new tokens at the same time, because of the nature of multithreaded code, and the question asker wants to keep only the first in that case.

Comment: @WarrenDew: your answer is practical and simple, however in your case your client is depending on server's token generation scheme. Hypothetically, if token server has bad implementation and generates some repeated tokens over short time then your scheme will perform bad. In xxa's scheme however, we are eliminating that theoretical possibility too and client is completely independent of server's token generation scheme.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming, your clients are acting quickly and often, and that time needed to get new token could be few times longer than few client requests, you must introduce some sort of locking.

If you assume, that token is received within 2 seconds, you could set up following rules:

use cache with keys "token" and "locked".

If there is not content for token, and locked is empty, set "lock" to True and try to get new token. As you are done, remove the lock and store new token.

If there is a token, try to use it.

If a token you have is failing, get from cache current token and if it differs, try to use new value. If there is no token, and "lock" is True, wait 2 seconds and try again. If no new token is found, try to get the token yourself (again, use "lock" True).

In short:

- if "token" found, try using it
- if "token" fails, delete it from cache and set up "lock", get new token, remove lock.
- if no "token", check if there is a "lock", if yes, wait 2 seconds, get new token if available, if not available, try getting it on your own.

Comment: Are you trying to enforce mutual exclusion with _[if] "lock" is True, wait 2 seconds and try again_? There are at least two fundamental problems with that: 1. does not work, 2. uses busy waiting

Comment: @xaa Yes, `if lock is True: time.sleep(2)` is the way. I would not call it mutual exclusion. My answer is in some scenarios waiting a moment to lower a chance, that multiple expensive requests for new token are running concurrently. And instead of `time.sleep(2)` the code could do something else and try later instead. How did you come to a conclusion "it does not work"? Also not sure, what you mean by "busy waiting". Does `time.sleep(2)` falls into this category? Is this a fundamental problem?

Comment: This is getting offtrack, you should ask this as a question